# Optional arguments in Fortran, when the signature of the function call is not initially known

Tags: python, fortran, optional-parameters

I have a fortran subroutine that takes many optional arguments and I am trying to build a python interface for it

```
subroutine myfunc(mandatory, A, B, C, result)
   integer, intent(in) :: mandatory
   integer, optional, intent(in) :: A, B, C
   integer, intent(out) :: result
end subroutine myfunc
```

In the python function call the mandatory arguments are given, while the optional arguments are given as key/value pairs in a dictionary. The fortran function that interfaces with python takes the arguments of the python call and checks if particular keys exists and stores it in boolean variables.

The python call would looks something like this

```
result = pymyfunc(1, {'A': 1, 'C': 2})
```

And the interface function will hold boolean values

```
is_A = .true.
is_B = .false.
is_C = .true.
```

Then it is about building the logic of all possible combinations of optional values in an if/else block to appropriatelly call the fortran routine. In this case:

```
...
else if (is_A .and. .not. is_B .and. is_C) then

   call myfunc(mandatory,A=A,C=C,result)
...
```

Now, this if/else block is manageable for 3 optional arguments. But you can see how this could explode in cases where more optional arguments exist.

I wonder if there is a more intelligent way of solving this. Something that I might be missing on how fortran handles the function calling signatures.

Comment: What are the *semantics* when `myfunc` doesn't receive a value for `B`, for example? if it's equivalent to using a default value for `B`, then why not just explicitly pass that default value when it's missing from the dict passed in from Python?

Comment: I find the above description a bit confusing. A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with just 2 or 3 optional arguments would really help.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel the `myfunc` routine has internal `if (present(var)) then` blocks. The optional arguments modify the internal calculation of `result`. So, if `A` is present, the value of `result` (determined by `mandatory`), changes. If `B` is present it changes the previous modification done by `A` etc.

Comment: I don't know it can help for the python case, but from C passing a null pointer to an optional argument of a Fortran routine is like if the argument was absent.

Comment: It feels a bit hacky to do it this way, but maybe it would work better to take `POINTER` arguments instead of `OPTIONAL` and do an `ASSOCIATED` check in the routine?  I think it would allow you to have cleaner code in the caller.

Comment: Hi @Craig thanks for your answer. I've got a similar solution. No need to change the signature of the `myfunc` routine. Instead you can default `A`, `B`, and `C` in the main program to be pointers pointing at `null`. Then point them to the required `target` variables as needed in the main program. Reading (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Argument-passing-conventions.html), absent optional arguments are denoted as `null` pointers, so you can just pass all the pointers. Some of those will point to targets and some will just be `null`.